# Why wont this code output the result?

Tags: python

```
print "HEllo !!"
print "Today, I will calculate something for you !!"
print "Enter your first number"
num1 = raw_input()
print "enter your second number"
num2 = raw_input()
print "type 1 for ADDITION"
print "type 2 for SUBTRACTION"
print "type 3 for MULTIPLICATION"
print "type 4 for DIVISION"
press=raw_input()
if press == 1:
   result = num1 + num2
   print result
if press == 2 :
   result = num1 - num2
   print result
if press == 3:
   result = num1 * num2
   print result
if press == 4:
   result = num1/num2
   print result
```

it work perfectly before the if statements, but doesn't output anything 
and displays this '>>>'.

Comment: Could you show the output you are getting?

Comment: `raw_input` is a string, it will **never** be e.g. `1`. Try `'1'`.

Comment: how are you running it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is that you are getting a string input, and then comparing it directly to an integer value.  Since a `str` is not an `int` all your `if` statements evaluate to `False`.  Either compare directly to a string, or convert the input to `int`.

So you can do one of the following:

```
press=raw_input()
if press == '1':
   result = num1 + num2
   print result
if press == '2' :
   result = num1 - num2
   print result
if press == '3':
   result = num1 * num2
   print result
if press == '4':
   result = num1/num2
   print result
```

or

```
press=int(raw_input())
if press == 1:
   result = num1 + num2
   print result
if press == 2 :
   result = num1 - num2
   print result
if press == 3:
   result = num1 * num2
   print result
if press == 4:
   result = num1/num2
   print result
```

Comparing to strings here should be the preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

[`raw_input` returns a `str` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), hence the `press == 1` can never be true:

```
>>> a = raw_input()
1
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>> a == 1
False
>>> a == '1'
True
```

You need to either surround your numbers with quotes or cast the input as integer, using `int(press)` (but beware of the `ValueError` exception if the user input a non-numeric string)

Answer (score 1):

1. You're checking the input from `raw_input()`, which is a string, against integers. They never match, and your `if` blocks are never entered into.
2. You are accepting `num1` and `num2` as strings, not integers. Use `input()` instead.

Try this instead:

```
print "HEllo !!"
print "Today, I will calculate something for you !!"
print "Enter your first number"
num1 = input()
print "enter your second number"
num2 = input()
print "type 1 for ADDITION"
print "type 2 for SUBTRACTION"
print "type 3 for MULTIPLICATION"
print "type 4 for DIVISION"
press=raw_input()
if press == "1":
   result = num1 + num2
   print result
if press == "2":
   result = num1 - num2
   print result
if press == "3":
   result = num1 * num2
   print result
if press == "4":
   result = num1/num2
   print result
```